# Persist variables in SQL commands using C# and one connection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

So maybe someone can point me in right direction.

I have this massive SQL query that a .NET application is running (I'm going to try my best to explain since i cannot post code).

What I decided to do is break the query down so the database does not get deadlocks.

So long story short is there a way to keep all the variable

```
Declare @sometable as Table
```

since each `SqlCommand` needs the information and IDs from the queries before it.

This is using the same connection. I've been at this for 4 days now and my head is turning.

Here is some of my code i tried using the same command and changing the query text

```
foreach (var query in querys)
{
 command.CommandText = query;
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  try {
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (!reader.IsClosed)
ds.Tables.Add().Load(reader);
mergedResults.Add(ds);
 }
```

EDIT: here is a sample of the top of the massive query thatr needs to be used every where

```
DECLARE @dbID int;
DECLARE @idDomain int;
DECLARE @DomainName varchar(255);

DECLARE @IdDrivers TABLE
(
 idDriver int,
 startTime datetime,
 endTime dateTime
);
```

Comment: You need to give a bit more detail in your question / code. Do you want the results of one query to be used in the subsequent query? Or you have a few parameters that you want to reuse across queries? You might consider using Entity Framework (or another ORM) and move the subqueries into your C# code

Comment: I wish i can use an orm but the person that wrote did tried to reinvent the wheel and now we are stuck with it. technically all i need is the params and some of the sub queries insert info into the temp tables to use them even lower.  the original query was a 20k line code with selects declares etc...

Comment: Sure, google sql server table variables, and also temp tables.. and decide which is best for you. Sounds like it needs to be bundled up into a sproc too

Comment: the major issue is that all these temp variables are dynamic

Comment: You might consider using a 'global' (##) temp table in sql if you need to write to it in one query and read from it in a subsequent one.

Comment: does that work with the @dbID as well for example, and how is performance, the original creator of this, made the query run paraelle on 8 DB's at the same time

Comment: @Jonathan no need to make that global, usually; globals don't scale

Answer (score 3):

Anything starting with `@` (locals, parameters, table valued parameters, etc) are all scoped to a single SQL batch, so no: they cannot be persisted between batches. There *are* `#` temporary tables which are scoped to the connection, but this doesn't sound like a good solution. Slowing things down doesn't change deadlock behaviour, as locking semantics are per *operation*, not per batch - unless you have a spanning transaction, in which case *that* has impact. Either way: the number of batches is not a determining factor.

If you're getting deadlocks, you need to investigate the how and why of that. It might be that performing some reads (those followed by updates to the same data) with `UPDLOCK` might help, by taking exclusive locks sooner.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist your table variable across batches:

Instead of the table variable @IdDrivers, you could use a temporary table (#IdDrivers). Create this temp table in your first batch.

e.g.:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#IdDrivers') is not null drop table #IdDrivers

create table #IdDrivers (your required columns here)
```

Then your second batch can populate the temp table, and subsequent batches can read from it.

This should work, as long as you open the Sql connection before the first batch, and close it after the last batch has been executed.

You may want to create another #temp table, to store your variables like: @idDomain.

It is important that the batch which creates the temporary table NOT execute via sp_executesql behind the scenes - otherwise, your subsequent batches will not be able to see the temp table you created, due to scoping. e.g. if you attempt to pass parameters, then ADO.NET will use sp_executesql behind the scenes, so don't pass parameters to the sql which creates the temporary table.

Comment: if i would but the variables in table, then I would have to modify the subsequent queries to read from the table.